# How do correctly get String link from HtmlImage Object in Java?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I try in such way:

```
HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage((urlList.get(i).toString()));
```

And have:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: HtmlImage[<img src="http://media.animewallpapers.com/wallpapers/misc/misc_164_t.jpg?m=21312126359&quot;"
```

What is a correct way?

Comment: Regardless of how you get the String link, what you're trying to do makes no sense. You're trying to get an url that will return an image and cast the image as an HtmlPage. In simpler terms: an HTML file is not the same as a JPG file. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have link to image, i try to go there to let me extract more images. I have method to extract images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the `src` attribute from an image you need to use the [`getSrcAttribute()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlImage.html#getSrcAttribute%28%29) method. Suppose `myImage` is an HtmlImage object, this code would output the `src` attribute to the console:

```
System.out.println(myImage.getSrcAttribute());
```

As a side note, casting an image as an `HtmlPage` will most likely throw an exception.